# How to use rectorphp/rector on Yii2 projects?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm porting a Yii 1 project developed with PHP 5.6 to Yii 2 with PHP 7.3 and I'd like to use rectorphp/rector in order to improve the code quality and make use of latest PHP features.

I've already tried with rector installed via composer and the official Docker image.

Here's what I'm executing:

```php
vendor/bin/rector -c rector.yaml process . --level php73 --dry-run
```

This is the error thrown for all classes:

```
 [ERROR] Could not process "<my class>" file, due to:            
         "Analyze error: "Class <my class> was not found while trying to  
         analyse it - autoloading is probably not configured properly.". Include your files in "parameters >            
         autoload_paths".                                                                                               
         See https://github.com/rectorphp/rector#extra-autoloading".
```

I believe the issue is related to the Yii2 custom class loader.

How should I configure rector for my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, until I set up the autoload_paths in rector.yaml as the following:

```
# rector.yaml
parameters:
  autoload_paths:
    - '.'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sad. Does not resolve it for me. Using the actual rector composer. 
`__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php', __DIR__ . '/frontend', '.'` is my config and still getting.
"Analyze error: "Class frontend\widgets\PortraitWidget was not found

Comment: Would love to know if you got this sorted? We have a yii1 project that we can’t get rector working on. Tried auto loading all files. Also tried using yii.php as a bootstrap file but still get errors.